# how to hide the address bar in phonegap android

Tags: java, android, cordova

I've created an android app using phonegap. When I launch the app in the emulator there is no address bar is present in the screen. After I follow a link on the page, a new window launches and the address bar appears on the screen.. Is there any way to disable the address bar? Could you guys help me out... Below is the code

main.java

```
package org.phonegap.android;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.phonegap.*;

 public class phonegapgettingstarted extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try add**

```
//Full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Below your

```
     super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

**EDIT :**
Use Third-Party Plugins (ChildBrowser)
http://hiediutley.com/2011/03/30/phonegap-tutorial-series-4-using-a-third-party-plugin/

Read this tut

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/22863272/Hiding%20the%20status%20bar%20at%20the%20top%20in%20Android

*If you need more help , ask me*

Comment: i tried adding the above two lines  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
still having no effect...cud u help me out

Comment: check your main.xml , make sure your webview is set to 

android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: i m a noob..i didnt declared a web view in main.xml coz i m opening my url in index.html with the following javascript...function onLoad(){
   
          window.location.href = "http://www.skytel.mobi/iphone/";
       
     } should i make some changes?

Answer (score 1):

The latest (put out today, 9/9) phonegap Android plugin, ChildBrowser, has an option to show or not show the toolbar. Simon MacDonald's blog also clearly explains usage in android projects and the new locationChanged() feature. Blog [here](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/09/phonegap-android-childbrowser-revamp.html) and github plugin code [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins).

Comment: i m getting an error where a new file plugins.out.xml is generated automatically when i add the plugin " <plugin name="ChildBrowser" value="com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser.ChildBrowser"/>" in plugins.xml

Comment: thanks man dat totally worked..i don no wat de problem is but worked dis morinin pretty fine